# AccessControlException is not always thrown in threads from the common java pool

Tags: java

I have the following program:

```
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        ForkJoinTask<?> read = ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SecurityManager appsm = System.getSecurityManager();

                if (appsm != null) {
                    appsm.checkPermission(new PropertyPermission("os.arch", "read"));
                    System.out.println("Permissions are OK!!!!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No system mangerrr :(");
                }
            }
        });


        read.get();

        System.out.println("End of the program!");
}
```

I also set this system property:
`-Djava.security.manager`

My question is the following - why sometimes I get "End of the program!" written to the standard output, but sometimes I get `Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.arch" "read")` ?

Shouldn't it always throw me this exception since the common pool's threads are created without any permissions? Shouldn't this behavior be always the same and do not vary throughout the different executions?

I am running this from my IntelliJ IDE using Zulu OPEN JDK 8.0.252.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because tasks submitted to a `ForkJoinPool` may execute in the calling thread on `join`. In your case this happens when you call `read.get()`; most of the time a worker from the common pool picks up the task and executes it (and the security check fails), but sometimes the task runs in the calling thread (and the security check passes).

You can confirm this by logging the thread name.

```java
public void run() {
    SecurityManager appsm = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (appsm != null) {
        System.err.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        appsm.checkPermission(new PropertyPermission("os.arch", "read"));
        System.out.println("Permissions are OK!!!!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No system mangerrr :(");
    }
}
```

This will log `Thread: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1` when the security check fails and `Thread: main` when the security check passes.

The difference in behaviour between the two cases occurs because your main thread has `os.arch` `read` permission, but the threads in your common pool have no permissions.

From the `ForkJoinPool` javadoc:

> The common pool is by default constructed with default parameters, but these may be controlled by setting three system properties:
>
> - `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` - the parallelism level, a non-negative integer
> - `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory` - the class name of a ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory
> - `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.exceptionHandler` - the class name of a Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
>
> If a SecurityManager is present and no factory is specified, then the default pool uses a factory supplying threads that have **no Permissions enabled.**

The default security in the common pool is *very* conservative. It runs tasks with **no** privileges and cleans up `ThreadLocal` vars after task completion to prevent information leakage.

The common pool security has to be conservative because it's available to all code—if it defaulted to running under the main `SecurityManager` then any code you tried to sandbox further could escalate privileges by running tasks in the common pool.

If you wan't to allow code to run tasks in the common pool with the privileges allowed by the `SecurityManager` that you've configured on the command line then you'll have to set the `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory` to an implementation you provide, e.g.

```java
public final class CustomForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory implements ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory {
    @Override
    public ForkJoinWorkerThread newThread(ForkJoinPool pool) {
        return ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.newThread(pool);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, teppic!